# How to get only (..., 3) to (...., 1)?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an numpy with a shape of `(147, 120, 120, 3)`. I would like to get a copy of the array for shape of `(147, 120, 120, 1)`. The last two indices in the last dimension should be thrown out.

What function should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether you want to keep the 4th dimension or not:

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.random.rand(147, 120, 120, 3)

In [3]: b = a[:, :, :, 0].copy(); b.shape
Out[3]: (147, 120, 120)

# axis=-1 expands the last dimension
In [4]: b = np.expand_dims(a[:, :, :, 0], axis=-1); b.shape
Out[4]: (147, 120, 120, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to slice away the last two indices in the last dimension?
I think this is what you want

```
a = np.random.rand(147, 120, 120, 3)
b = a[...,:1]
b.shape
```

Output

```
(147, 120, 120, 1)
```

Ellipsis `...` can be used to generalize the empty slices `:`

Comment: To add to this, this returns a view. if you need a copy of it use `.copy()` on NumPy array.

Comment: @Ehsan Thanks, did not read the question properly.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to keep dimensions when indexing is to place the index in a list:

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(147, 120, 120, 3)
>>> a[:, :, :, [0]].shape
(147, 120, 120, 1)
>>> a[..., [0]].shape
(147, 120, 120, 1)
```

Where the `[0]` is a list with a single element, 0. Use `.copy()` if you want a copy of the array rather than a view.